# How to get the Id of corresponding th of td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id ="myid1">header1</th>
            <th id ="myid2">headre "2</th>
            <th id ="myid3">header3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>v1</td>
            <td>v2</td>
            <td>v3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>v10</td>
            <td>v11</td>
            <td>v12</td>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>v20</td>
            <td>v21</td>
            <td>v22</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>v30</td>
            <td>v31</td>
            <td>v32</td>                    
        </tr>
</table>
```

there can be thousands of row  .

i need to get the id of the td on which that perticulat td belongs to.

for example . if i click the third td of third row .. i should get the id of corresponding th , here it is myid3  (here its hard coded but it will set based on the value from server side)

```
$('tbody td').live('click', function() {
    var idOfTh = ??
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('td').click(function() {
        alert($('table th').eq($(this).index()).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Working JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6etRb/

You only need to use live delegation if the table rows are being added dynamically, and in that case you should use `.on()` as described by others.

Answer (score 1):

**The following answer is wrong, but I'm keeping the edit as it may help someone**

```
$('tbody td').live('click', function() {
    var tdIndex = $(this).parent('tr').indexOf($(this));
    var idOfTh = $(this).parent('table').find('tr').eq(tdIndex);
});
```

Untested, but theoretically should work.

**CORRECTION**

The above is incorrect, as pointed out by Felix Kling below. The correct way to get the index is simply by calling `$(this).index()`. I had presumed this would find the position of `$(this)` within the matched selector (in this case, every `<td>` in the `<tbody>`), but actually, if you pass the `index()` function no arguments, it finds the index **relative to its siblings**. Thanks to Felix for pointing out [the relevant documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: It's not correct. Get the index like this: `var tdIndex = $(this).index()`. Also, `.parent('table')` should be `.closest('table')` (`.parent('table')` won't select any element since the parent node of the `td` is not a `table`) and `.find('tr')` should be `.find('th')`.

Comment: Thanks Felix. But wouldn't that get the index of the td within **all** td elements in the matched selector, not just the row?

Comment: No, it gets the index among its siblings: *"If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements."* (http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: @ChrisFrancis: That's what I thought too, but it looks like Felix is right: http://jsfiddle.net/6vYgm/

Comment: Awesome - did not expect that behaviour! Also did not read the documentation... ;)

Comment: Then go ahead and fix your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq()` method, try the following:

```
 $('tbody td').live('click', function() {
     var ind = $(this).index()
     var idOfTh = $('thead th:eq('+ind+')').attr('id')
 });
```

Please note that `live()` is deprecated you can use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `.live()` function has been deprecated. If you want to delegate events, use either `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()`. I'll assume you're using `.on()` for the rest of this, but there's only a minor syntax change (switch the first two arguments) if you have to use `.delegate()`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'tbody td', function() {
    var tdIndex = $(this).index();
    // ^ gets the index of the clicked element relative to its siblings
    var thId = $('thead th:eq(' + tdIndex + ')')[0].id; 
    // ^ selects the th element in the same position in its row, then gets its id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
$('td').click(function() {
   var colNum = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)) + 1;
   alert($('#myid' + colNum).text());    
});​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8SWW/4/

Answer (score 0):

The handler can looks like:

```
function() {
    var self = this
    var th_num = 0;

    $(this).parent().children().each(function(num){
        if (this == self) {
            th_num = num;
            return false
        }
    });

    var th_id = $('thead th').eq(th_num).attr('id');
}
```